# show or hide div id in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

html

```
<input type="image" name="Generate" src="../images/buttons/generate.gif" align="middle" onclick="javascript:return validate();" title="Generate"/>
```

javascript

```
function validate() {
    Generate();
}

function Generate() {
    var date = new Date();
    var curdate = date.getDate() + '/' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getFullYear();
    var frstDate = document.formname.fromDate.value;
    if (frstDate == curdate) {
        document.getElementById("block1").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("block2").style.display = "none";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("block1").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("block2").style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

but this is now working, as the div id is not getting into my generate function
and i need to use a single button even if we select current date or less than that

can u please suggest

Comment: `function validate(name) {
    Generate(divtags);
}` 
should be

`function validate(name) {
    Generate(name);
}`

Comment: Plz debug the values of frstDate and curdate. I think you will find solution your own.

Comment: "The div id is not getting into my generate function" - *which* div ID? Please post your full HTML.

Comment: please keep complete html code.bits and pieces are not clear

Comment: Please post all of your HTML. This small piece is not enough to solve your problem.

Comment: return is only needed when you return something from the function.

Answer (score 0):

This is your problem:

In the `onclick` attribute you have `validate('Generate');` which is fine if that is the `id` of the div you need to target. However in your `validate` function definition you don't pass on the `name` variable to the `Generate` function.

Instead you pass on a 'non existent' variable `divtags` to the `Generate` function. (I say 'non existent' as without the rest of your code I can't tell if it exists or not, but it most probably doesn't)

Answer (score 0):

Two possible problems.

First (the one I don't think is causing your issue): `validate()` has a parameter called `name`, which goes unused. Instead, in `validate()` you call `Generate(divtags)`, which should cause an error, unless `divtags` is a global variable (in which case you probably don't need to pass it as a parameter). If this is the problem, `validate()` needs to look like this:

```
function validate(name) {
    Generate(name); // passes argument available within the scope of validate()
}
```

Second (I think this is your issue): `Generate()` doesn't use the parameter passed into it. In other words, it doesn't do anything with the `divtags` argument. You try to show/hide `block1` and `block2`, which, given the limited HTML you've provided, may or may not exist. I believe you're trying to change the display of elements that don't exist, and this is your error.

I'll update this answer if you clarify your question with more HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the assumed solution based on your unclear question. You want to show and hide divs is fine. But atlast you need to submit the data to server. so make it clear that do you want to do this event on submit or when you focus out from the date field.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <style>
        #block1,#block2{display:none;}
    </style>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        function validate() {
            var frstDate = document.forms[0].date.value;
            if (frstDate === "") {
                alert("please select date");
                return false;
            } else {
                Generate();
                return false;
            }
        }

        function Generate() {
            var date = new Date();
            var curdate = date.getDate() + '/' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getFullYear();
            var frstDate = document.forms[0].date.value;
            if (frstDate === curdate) {
                document.getElementById("block1").style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("block2").style.display = "none";
            } else {
                document.getElementById("block1").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("block2").style.display = "block";
            }
        }

        $(function() {
            $("#datepicker").datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'});
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="date"/>
        <input type="image" src="" name="generate" onclick="return validate()"/>
    </form>
    <div id="block1">block1</div>
    <div id="block2">block2</div>
</body>
```